# Configuring POP3 with Sendgrid - Can't receive emails but can send them

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid

All I have is an email client ([emClient](https://www.emclient.com/)) and a working sendgrid account. When prompted to enter an email address, I can happily put `anything@mydomain.com` and it will confirm that it works with SMTP. I can also send emails using this client. I authenticate with the username apikey and my api key.

However, these emails are permanently stuck in the "outbox" and are constantly sent over and over again, presumably because the client has no confirmation that they were sent. When trying to set up a new account under this domain, I setup my "incoming server" as smtp.sendgrid.net and provide my credentials and it sort-of works (after prompting me for my authentication?).
[image: SMTPAuthenticationOKbutIMAPnot]

As you can see, SMTP authenticates just fine and this makes sense as I am seemingly able to send email. However, both IMAP and POP3 when I select them in the "incoming server" are stuck on this "testing" stage until they fail.

Now, if we skip ahead to me sending something out - basically, it works. I receive the email on the destination, it does not get marked as spam and it comes from my domain and my name.

However, when I attempt to receive an email on the `anything@mydomain.com` one, it just doesn't do anything. I don't get an error from gmail that it wasn't delivered, it simply just doesn't get delivered.

For my domain settings, I have the following configured:

[image: dnssettingsforemaildomain]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

While SendGrid allows you to send emails over SMTP or via the API, SendGrid is not a full mailbox that you can connect to over POP3 or IMAP. You cannot connect to SendGrid using an email client, that is not what it is intended for. SendGrid is not a mailbox, but a way to programmatically send and receive emails and other email based events.

The way to receive incoming emails is via the [inbound parse webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook). When you have set that up, incoming emails to your configured domain will cause a webhook, an HTTP request, to be sent to a URL you configured, with all the information about the email.

Comment: Can you recommend anything that could replace Sendgrid in this case? It feels like such a let down, that I could potentially use the same solution as a personal mailbox in conjunction with my business email which needs to be sent out to thousands of people.

Comment: If you want to receive emails to a domain to a regular inbox, you can set that up as normal with any email provider ([Fastmail](https://www.fastmail.com/) comes to mind as a good provider of business email inboxes). You can then authenticate the domain and send mass emails from that domain with SendGrid. The only thing you can't really combine is receiving emails to the normal inbox and getting them as a webhook. Does that help?

Comment: Yep, thanks, will mark your answer as the one.